# how to debug iis 7.5 application pool?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm having a problem with my IIS 7.5. problem that maybe I have caused yesterday after playing with application pools.
The problem is that website become very slow and the only way to fix it is to recycle the application pool.
When i try to access HTML file it's working fast but when i access classic ASP file it takes long time to load "Waiting for"

When i recycle the pool the problem solved for few seconds or minutes and my question is how do i debug it ? how do i know what cause the application pool to stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

you always have the possibility to debug classic asp applications.

set the debug properties in your iis for your web application like so:
server-side Debugging active: true

then you can use the "stop" keyword in your classic asp files to set a "breakpoint". a popup will be raised to ask you how you want to debug your asp file (e.g.visual Studio)